# right calf and right foot pain during cycling

Tags: bicycling

I started using a recumbent bike in my home to use as a life long endeavor to be fit. The problem that has arisen is that my right foot and calf hurt after a few minutes on the bike. This is entirely different than the first 2 weeks I was on it. While before I could do one stretch of an hour cycling, I can only do 10-15 minutes at a time before my right calf starts building up pain and my right foot aches. My assumption is that my right leg is either longer or shorter than my left and is in imbalance when working out. I thought about getting custom made shoes, but my recumbent bike doesn’t allow for shoes bigger than a docker or sandals/slippers. Does anyone know what's going on and how to fix my problem?

Comment: We can't diagnose your pains over the internet, unfortunately. You should see a doctor about this.

Comment: You can adjust for leg length with shoe insoles, or by packing up the pedal on the short-leg side.   Recumbents are often slightly asymmetric too, sometimes being designed 10-20mm off true centerline.